# Java emulating the "open with" on a .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm trying to automate an arduous process but I've run into a wall that I can't seem to google my way around.

[This is the process that I'm trying to automate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvtHy.png)

The batch file contains:

```
cd %~dp0

"%~dp0raindrop.exe" -g om -i %1 -o "%~dp1
PAUSE
```

What I'm trying to do: Stream in from a folder a bunch of '.sm' files and pass them one by one through the bat file creating a Folder for the outputted file created from the .bat process.

Explaining what these set of commands do would be great as I would prefer to create one more fit for my purpose. Which is bulk converting and sorting, so the output directory assuming thats handled in that batch file would need to be understood.

[What i've tried at the moment its just running the .bat as is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sY5A.png)

Comment: I can't tell, are you trying to simulate that batch file by "typing" the keystrokes?  That won't work, because the `%~dp0` and `%1` things are only interpreted inside a batch file.  However, all that does is expand to the name of the directory that contains the batch file.  All you have to do is substitute the right value.  `%1` is the first argument to the script, `%~dp1` extracts the path part of the 1st argument.

Comment: Trying pass my own parameters through and grab the output without having to do the "drag and drop" over the batch file itself since I can't do that in Java. But I don't know what any of the script is doing so I have no idea what to change in order to achieve it, if its even possible.

Comment: Ok I found something that works: 
```
String.format("\"%s\" -g om -i \"%s\" -o \"%s\"",
                rainDrop.toString(), smFile.toString(), output.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%1` is window-batch-ese for 'the first parameter'. That makes some sense, I hope.

`%0` is window-batch-ese for 'the batch file itself'. If you think about it now knowing what `%1` means, this does make a little bit of sense: It's the '0th parameter' - the one to the left of the first parameter, which is the batch file itself.

`%~letters0` is a way to tell windows; I want `%0`, but, I want you to modify it. There are many letters. `d` in particular means 'drive letter', and `p` means path.

Thus,

`%~dp0` is windows-batch-ese for 'the full path (including drive letter) to the *directory* where the batch file currently executing lives.

`%~dp1` is windows-batch-ese for 'take param 1 and turn it into an absolute path, then give me the directory that contains this argument.

Thus, you should now be able to recreate what this batch script does in pure java:

1. It runs the file `raindrop.exe`, by asking windows to run that by providing the full, absolute path to that executable, which is located in the same place the batch file is located.
2. It then passes 6 arguments to it:

- `-g`
- `-om`
- `-i`
- the first parameter
- `-o`
- if the first parameter resolves to a file, then that file, turned into an absolute path, and then the directory (i.e. if passing 'foo.txt', and that is in `C:\example\whatever\foo.txt`, the last arg is `C:\example\whatever`).

Use ProcessBuilder and you can recreate this feature fully.

NB: Your batch script is probably broken; it's missing a closing quote. Also, the fact that `%1` is not quoted means that any files with spaces in it will also break this batch script. I assume you have no need to replicate these bugs in the java take on this.

NB: Run raindrop.exe with ProcessBuilder. Forget the bat file, you don't want to run that.